# select all animation AND shader node keyframes

Tags: keyframes

im trying to move the animation in my scene backward in time. for that i need to move all keyframes, but after selecting all objects i realize that the timeline editor only shows their keyframes WITHOUT the corresponding shader node keyframes

i could manually select every object and navigate into the shader editor and select all nodes there but it seems like a tedious task.

so my question: is there a quick way to truly select all keyframes in a scene?

Comment: I was really hoping you would have a response by now because I have the same question.